# C pointer to an array of string and array name disambiguation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I found this piece of code:

```
char *array[4]={"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
char *(*ptr)[4]=&array;
```

In comment it says:

> `ptr`: It is pointer to array of string of size 4

What is then by definition a variable *array*?

And what would be in this case?

```
char array[4]={"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
```

since I found this:

```
double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
double *p = balance;
```

that says:

> An array name is a constant pointer to the first element of the array,
>   Thus, the above program fragment assigns `p` as the address of the first
>   element of `balance`.

Okay, I think got this. So to try to answer my first question, is then variable `array` a constant pointer to the first character of the first element of the array, namely `'a'`? I say this due to the `*` sign in front of the variable name.

Second question answer would just be: `array` is the constant pointer to the first element of the array.

Apparently, still having problems with pointers and arrays in C...

Comment: `char array[4]={"aa","bb","cc","dd"};` is invalid.

Comment: Short answer: No. The array-to-pointer conversion (decay) only happens on the first level.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is asking, but there's nothing going on here that's nearly as complicated as what you imagine. An array is an array, but when used as a pointer, it acts like a pointer to its first (0th) element.

Comment: Couldn't you just ask **one** question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Array is not a constant pointer in C.  It is dead wrong.

Array decays into pointer to first element in most cases. That doesn't mean it is a pointer.

Constant thing is coming in your mind because array is non-modifiable lvalue. So you can't use it as one where it is being modified.

From §[6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, *an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue*. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

This explains what happened - `balance` in that statement is converted into pointer to the first element. The first element is `double` and a pointer to it is `double*` and that pointer contains address of `balance[0]`.

This paragraph also points out why the `&array` is `char* (*)[]` because array used as operand to `&` address of operator is a case where array is not converted to pointer. That is why the first statement is legal. (Note that `char *(*ptr)[4]` is a pointer to an array of 4 `char*`-s. Here the address of `array` is assigned to `ptr`).

from §[6.3.2.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1)

> ...*A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type*, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type.

Whatever the source be, maybe it tried to show you this idea that arrays are not modifiable lvalues so statements like `balance++` in C is illegal given that `balance` is an array name.

Without going awry or confusing the correct way to describe what array would be from standard §[6.2.5p20](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20)

> An array type describes a *contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type*. The element type shall be complete whenever the array type is specified. *Array types are characterized by their element type and by the number of elements in the array*. An array type is said to be derived from its element type, and if its element type is T , the array type is sometimes called ''array of T ''. The construction of an array type from an element type is called ''array type derivation''

Also note one thing, when you used `char a[]={"aa","bb"};` - this is wrong in the sense that string literals are char arrays which decays into pointer - so it is an array of `char*`-s not array of `char`.

Answer (score 1):

No. Arrays are **not** pointers. There's something called "array-to-pointer conversion" (decaying), but it only happens on the first level, and does not make arrays and pointers the same thing.

In your code snippet:

```
char array[4]={"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
```

`array` can be uses as (decays to) a pointer to **another pointer to the first character of the string**, or in other words, the first element in the array. There's no "the first character of" the first element, since that's the second level, and there are other matters.

This can be comprehended in another way: `balance` can be converted to a pointer to `balance[0]`, so we have `balance == &(balance[0])`. But it can never happen that `array = &(&(array[0][0]))` because the address-of operator returns an rvalue, or anyway a value that cannot be taken address again, so `array` is *not* a pointer to `array[0][0]`.

Since you're using string literals, which are effectively constant pointers to characters, the content of `array` looks like:

```
           array
          +----------+
array --> | array[0] |  --> "aa"
          +----------+
          | array[1] |  --> "bb"
          +----------+
          | array[2] |  --> "cc"
          +----------+
          | array[3] |  --> "dd"
          +----------+
```

Therefore, `array` is **not** a pointer to any character, it may be converted to (decay to) a pointer to another pointer of `char`, but it won't ever be converted to a pointer to the first character, `'a'`.